# Identify empty VALUE in XML files and return exit command?

Tags: shell-script, python, git, xml, hook

For instance, I have an XML file with the below content and the "NAME" Author and Assignee(s) have empty "VALUE". The main aim is to implement a check that can be applied to find XML files that have empty VALUE's. So is there a way I can create a script which can be used as a git hook(pre-commit) so that input to the script are the files that are being called by git commit (all files in that repo) or git commit (filename). And then the script should not allow to commit if the XML file has empty VALUEs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PACKAGE format-rev="7" prog-version="2020.2.98572" xmlns=https..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <INFORMATION format-rev="2" xsi:type="packageInfo">
        <ATTRIBUTES>
            <ATTRIBUTE xsi:type="attributeInst">
                <NAME xsi:type="string">Type</NAME>
                <VALUE xsi:type="string">MANUAL</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE xsi:type="attributeInst">
                <NAME xsi:type="string">Severity</NAME>
                <VALUE xsi:type="string">Normal</VALUE>
            <ATTRIBUTE xsi:type="attributeInst">
                <NAME xsi:type="string">Author</NAME>
                <VALUE xsi:type="string"/>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE xsi:type="attributeInst">
                <NAME xsi:type="string">Assignee(s)</NAME>
                <VALUE xsi:type="string"/>
        </ATTRIBUTES>
```

Is there a better approach than the one shown below? TIA

```
def xmlvalidator():
    dirlist = []
    dirlist.append(os.getcwd().replace("\\","/"))
    filelists = filelist(dirlist)
    Flagvallists = []
    for filename in filelists:
        xtree = et.parse(filename)
        root = xtree.getroot()
        xroot = root[0][0]
        flag = 0
        flagval = []

        for i in range(len(xroot)):
            #xroot here should ATTRIBUTES (ATTRIBUTE IN ATTRIBUTES)
            s_name = xroot[i][0].text
            s_value = xroot[i][1].text
            if s_value == None:
                flagval.append(s_name)   
                flag = 1      

        if flag==1:             
            flagval.append(filename)
        Flagvallists.append(flagval)
        #sys.exit(1)
        #return True
    return Flagvallists
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Paul_Pedant Seems like a simple and great solution, but how can the input be the same as the one called by git commit? and not the filename(A.xml)

```
if grep "<VALUE[^>]*/>" A.xml; then
    echo errors found
else
    echo not found
fi
```

Comment: I suggest to check the XML against a Schema definition, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/129401/10622916 for available tools and https://stackoverflow.com/q/28987004/10622916 for a schema that checks for an empty value.

Comment: Assuming consistency in the input, a missing value appears always to be short-form (not requiring a separate `</VALUE>`. So a RE of `<VALUE[^>]*/>` matches an empty value. A script that silently greps for that and returns zero status (to mean at least one missing value) is a one-liner.

Comment: I don't do git. You mentioned a "git hook" so I assumed you knew how to glue my snippet in place. I would assume git commit would pass you the names so you could iterate over them in a script, or pass you the content so you could read it through a pipe, and you could return an exit code that would abort the commit. Or you just run the snippet manually first, for each file you want to commit.